# Class is not found with ViewComposer in Lravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use Laravel view composer. I have registered my class in config/app.php but I keep getting the following error:

> "Class App\Http\ViewComposers\PostComposer does not exist

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('plain','App\Http\ViewComposers\PostComposer');
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

my post composer class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposer;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Post;

class PostComposer
{
    public function comspose(View $view)
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $view->with('postha', $posts );
    }
}
```

and here is the screenshot of my browser:

[image: browser error]

[![folder structure in my app][]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lesmT.png)

Answer (score 3):

Your namespace is wrong.

You're importing from (plural):

```
App\Http\ViewComposers\PostComposer
```

but the namespace of your ViewComposer isn't plural:

```
App\Http\ViewComposer
```

Answer (score 0):

try it : `namespace App\Http\ViewComposer` To `namespace App\Http\ViewComposers`